# cookie passing between viewcontrols

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am develope iphone app. i have a questions. i created php - mysql script. Then i created login screen on xcode. i send http request and i read cookies. But i wanna do something other viewcontrols. So i need save phpsessid cookie and send http request with cookies. my questions is how make i do?

FirstViewControl(login screen) .m file

```
#import "SecondViewControl.h"

// If you want to get all of the cookies:
                        NSArray * all = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iosapp.com"]];
                        NSLog(@"How many Cookies: %d", all.count);
                        // Store the cookies:
                        // NSHTTPCookieStorage is a Singleton.
                        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies:all forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iosapp.com/"] mainDocumentURL:nil];
                        // Now we can print all of the cookies we have:
                        for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in all)
                        {
                            SecondViewControl* myViewController = [[SecondViewControl alloc]initWithCookie:cookie];
                            NSLog(@"Name: %@ : Value: %@, Expires: %@", cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.expiresDate);

                        }
```

SecondViewControl.h

```
    @interface SecondViewControl : UIViewController{
    NSHTTPCookie * _cookie;//ivar declaration
}
-(id)initWithCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie;//function prototype
```

SecondViewControl.m

```
@implementation SecondViewControl
-(id)initWithCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie
{
    _cookie = cookie;
    return self;
}
```

SecondViewControl.m button

```
- (IBAction)homeb:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ : Value: %@, Expires: %@", _cookie.name, _cookie.value, _cookie.expiresDate);

}
```

And not working. null cookie :/ NSlog.

```
2014-04-26 04:35:22.186 login[73801:60b] Name: PHPSESSID : Value: 49c1ed0c570dd85a3f7593c7e039086d, Expires: (null)
    2014-04-26 04:35:22.186 login[73801:60b] Login SUCCESS
    2014-04-26 04:35:29.091 login[73801:60b] Name: (null) : Value: (null), Expires: (null) (clicked seconviewcontrol button.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for your first question:"How do I pass to the next viewController"

assume this is you viewController.h

```
 @interface viewController : UIViewController
 {
     NSHTTPCookie * _cookie;//ivar declaration
 }

-(id)initWithCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie;//function prototype
 @end
```

in viewController .m

```
  @implementation viewController
  -(id)initWithCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie
  {
       _cookie = cookie;
       return self;
  }
     ... ... ...
  @end
```

in you login

```
  viewController* myViewController = [viewController alloc]initWithCookie:cookie];
```

or you can simply make a setter inside your viewController.h

```
 @interface viewController : UIViewController
 {
     NSHTTPCookie * _cookie;//ivar declaration
 }

-(void)setCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie;//function prototype
 ...
 @end
```

in viewController .m

```
  @implementation viewController
  -(void)setCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie
  {
       _cookie = cookie;
  }
     ... ... ...
  @end
```

in you login

```
  viewController* myViewController = [viewController alloc]init];//or init with xib name or whatever is that

  //and then 

   [myViewController setCookie:cookie];//here you go you just passed cookie to your viewControllers ivar.
```

in .h

```
 @interface viewController : UIViewController
 {
    NSMutableArray* _cookiesArray;
 }

-(void)addCookieCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie;//function prototype
 @end
```

in viewController .m

```
  @implementation viewController
  -(void)addCookieCookie :(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie
  {
       if(!cookiesArray)//when you are running for first time you should to init the array like this
       {
           cookiesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       }
       [cookiesArray addObject:cookie];
  }
     ... ... ...
```

Now you can have an array inside your secondViewController
      @end

About your second question : please make a separate question explain yourself and show us the code.

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer. I begin few days ago to lelarn ios programming. So how can i declare an ivar?

Comment: as I pasted above inside the `@interface` s brackets you can declare an iVars. You can also declare properties with `@property` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for help but can u check my edited question? i trying 2 days but always fail..

Comment: 1)It seems like you wanna pass cookie array and not a single cookie.
2)the problem is you cookies are null ..
3) you should use the second solution I passed (in that case you would pass only the last cookie) if you wanna pass array of cookies you should ivar `nsarray` and then to addObject to it (eachCookie)

Comment: I will update the answer how can you use the array ... but however I dont understand your cookie logic ... you will have to find that yourself.